# DataPower monitoring or validation techniques

Tags: ibm-datapower

How to improve datapower monitoring ? I want to improve our monitoring techniques say for example, want to check that all objects (FSH /MQFSHs, SSl proxy, crypto profile etc) are up and incase if it goes down , should be notified by email or something. checking number of files in file management ondisk folders.Basically validate the adapter after deployment (we use soapUi to test adapter functionality, however something else to improve or added validation).please suggest any ideas that can be implemented as a process improvement on Datapower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can get the status off all your domains using this soma call. You can test this using soap UI. You can get the list of various soma calls using the datapower mgmt wsdl (available in datapower store directory).

```
  <!-- get all the domains -->
  <xsl:variable name="domainsList">
     <dp:url-open target="{$XML-MGMT-URL}" response="responsecode">
        <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
           <env:Body>
              <dp:request xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management">
                 <dp:get-status class="DomainStatus"/>
              </dp:request>
           </env:Body>
        </env:Envelope>
     </dp:url-open>
  </xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using SOMA commands of XML management interface to check the object status.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best approach but this is how i have implemented it. You can always create a testing service in DataPower with/without interactive java application to perform all the soap test you are performing using soapUI. You can perform SOMA/AMP calls to check the status of objects, ping external services, etc. You can schedule these test on a regular interval or manual.

Depending how you set it up, you can either generate an email with status of each object/service you are testing or create a html dashboard that records the current status of everything.

Comment: Thanks ! Can you provide a reference or an example

Comment: Please check the separate answer that i posted below.